# Check if 3 row's re filled and do something

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with 2 sheet's, one to add data and the other to sum all the added data.
The one to add data will have 5 columns and i want it only to add the data only when 3 of the columns (in this case A, B and C) are filled with values.

I was using getRange class to get all values from the line but i have no idea how to retrieve the length of the data and if it was 3 to add that new data into the other sheet.

This is what i have:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var a = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  if( a.getName() == "Movimentos detalhados" ) {
    rowValue = a.getActiveCell().getRow();
    colValue = a.getActiveCell().getColumn();

    lValues = a.getRange( rowValue, 1, rowValue, 3).getValues();

    Browser.msgBox(lValues + " --->" + lValues[0].length);

    //if(lValues[0].length == 3) {

    //}

  }
}
```